# Nested WP_Query breaking loop

Tags: posts, wp-query, query-posts

I'm using `WP_Query` to get all pages without subpages. For each page I'm using again `WP_Query` to get all child pages of the current page inside the first loop.

This all works fine and I'm getting the expected result.

But when now using a third `WP_Query` on one of the sub pages, the second level loop breaks.

I already tried the functions `wp_reset_query()` and `wp_reset_postdata()` but they didn't do the trick.

Also I tried to save the `global $wp_query` and `global $post` and reset them after the loop, but this didn't help too.

How do I implement nested queries in WP?

**Edit** As requested (and how it would have been correct) here is my code. I also realized that my problem does not apply only to the third, but also to the second loop.

```
$all_pages = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_parent' => 0));

while($all_pages->have_posts()) {
    $all_pages->the_post();
    include(get_page_template());
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

In the page templates I'm using the following code to get child pages:

```
// child page content rendered here, depending on template

if($post->post_parent == 0) {
    $child_pages = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'page', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'page_parent' => $post->post_parent));

    while($child_pages->have_posts()) {
        $child_pages->the_post();
        include(get_page_template());
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

I can execute WP_Queries on the child pages. But when then using `the_post();` the `$child_page` loop stops executing.

Comment: Please show your complete loop instead of just a description of it.

Comment: I will provide it later this evening, when I'm back in office.

Comment: you should use `get_template_part` not `include` to pull in template files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer. I think I had another issue anywhere so my real problem could not be solved. I did it like this:

In the page templates at first I'm doing

```
global $post;
$saved_post = $post;
```

and at the end of the page templates this:

```
if($saved_post) {
    $post = $saved_post;
}
```

I have two files (page.header.php and page.footer.php) which I include in every single page template, which do the save and restore.

There might be a better solution, so I'm still happy with answers and ideas :-)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a single query:

```
$parent_only = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_parent' => 0,
) );
```

If you want to have all children of a specific page (for e.g.) in the loop (or on a request that returns `TRUE` for `is_singular()`), use `get_the_ID()` as argument for `post_parent`.

#### Edit (after seeing the full loop in the updated question)

The [`get_page_template()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_page_template/) function should  be used in the `template_include` filter callback. When you look at  [`~/wp-includes/template-loader.php` and its internals](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d0cfa40983ad46dadbb6dd0a5808660f57ccea36/wp-includes/template-loader.php#L44), then you will see the following:

```
is_page() && $template = get_page_template()
```

This function is not meant to be used inside templates. When you want to include template parts, then stick with `get_template_part()` instead.

I *assume* you want to build a list of pages where each child page is listed below the parent page - and each child-child page is listed below the parent page. This can be done with [`wp_list_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) <sup>[Source](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_list_pages/)</sup>:

```
<ul>
    ?>
    wp_list_pages( array(
        'title_li' => sprintf(
            '<h2>%s</h2>'
            __( 'Pages sorted by parent', 'your-textdomain' )
        ),
    ) );
    <?php
</ul>
```

Now this will just output a list of pages. When you look closer at the list of arguments, then you can use: `child_of` and `echo` as well:

```
// Get all parent pages:
$pages = get_pages( array(
    'number' => 0, // get *all* pages
) );

// Container:
$output = array();
// Loop and fetch
foreach ( $pages as $page )
{
    $output[] = wp_list_pages( array(
        'title_li' => '...',
        'echo'     => false,
        'child_of' => $page->ID,
    ) );
}

// Build the output:
foreach ( $output as $p )
    // etc.
```

Above example is just meant to clarify internals. Of course you can simply adjust the `depth` argument, so `wp_list_pages()` fetches parents and their children to build an unordered HTML list.

So the correct approach would be to pass in the needed `depth` and if you need custom ordering, then go with a custom walker assigned to the `walker`-key.

### Summed up - core does it for you per default.

Comment: You can just use this code from @kaiser in several `foreach` loops.

Comment: I'm actually not doing anything else. And as I stated in the OP, it kind of works. Only when using a third query, it breaks the loop... I will provide my code when I'm back in office

Comment: @Julian **Please** edit your question and _show your COMPLETE loop_ !

Comment: @kaiser read my comment, I already stated to do so ;-)

Comment: I don't see any loop in your question ... just a description...

Comment: I had no time yet. Just added the info, sorry, was too busy

Comment: So I think you didn't get my problem. I know how to get only main pages and children of a specific page. My problem is now that I don't know how, but that it does not do, what I want. The children loop stops executing when using `the_post` on one of the sub-pages!

Comment: Your assumption is false ;-) I already came across `wp_list_pages`. I'm actually building an one-page-site. My solution works and as I just need pages, `get_page_template` looked good. I'll look at `get_template_part` though, thanks for the tip

Comment: @Julian I hope you see the problem with me making _assumptions_ : You have not provided enough information in your question. Please edit it and explain your whole case and please keep this in mind for later questions. It's quite disappointing if you want to help someone for free in your spare time and then end up like this.